# Not to delete child record on deleting parent table record

Tags: java, hibernate, rdbms, database, object-oriented-database

I am little bit newbie in Hibernate and DBMS and stuck on a problem. I have two table. One is `A` and second is `B`. There is Many-to-One relationship between these two tables. Now on removing one record from table `A` I do not want to delete the record from table `B`. What type of cascading strategy should I apply.

Please help.

Answer (score 0):

[Here](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/core/3.3/reference/en/html/objectstate.html#objectstate-transitive)'s what Hibernate manual says.
Based on what you wrote I think you should use `cascade="persist,merge,save-update"`